# Magento 2.1 store logo is showing 403 forbidden error

Tags: magento-2.1, logo

I installed magento 2.1. When I changed the logo, the file is returning 403 forbidden error in console.

I have checked in this forum and found a solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183218/magento2-admin-logo-showing-403-forbidden-error).

When I did this, the logo was visible for a brief moment then again it's back to showing 403 error.

Any insight on how to solve this would be very helpful.

Thank you!

URL: [Click here](http://sbazaar.webimprovise.com/)

Comment: its permission issue please check my answer.

Comment: Which is your current deploy mode?

Comment: @SHPatel, deployed as developer mode.

Comment: See my below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, the case was the logo file's ownership.

The uploaded file had root as owner. Following instructions of this [URL](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html), I found out the user for my installation. Then Changed the file ownership using chown.

```
chown <user> logo.png
```

FYI, file permission is set to: 644.

Answer (score 0):

**Enter the following commands in the order shown:**

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**After run permission command you need to run below commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did those. but few moments later, It back to showing 403 error. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183218/magento2-admin-logo-showing-403-forbidden-error - this is the first URL, I provided in my message. It has the same solution.

Comment: Yes, you can do it again and check.

Comment: doing it for last two days. same result every time. logo is shown. then after some time, it's 403 again!!

Answer (score 0):

commands you need to run

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: After running those commands, a fatal error message is shown stating that var/cache is not writable. To solve this, changed permission to 777. After that, the next reload shows the logo. Then again if the page is reloaded, the logo disappears and shows 403 error.

Comment: Apply properly permission to your magento setup.